# Ubuntu Server 16.04: benchmarking disks from terminal

Tags: 16.04, server, hard-drive, benchmarks

### Situation:

I need to benchmark a disk (check the `read` speed and the `write` speed). I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04, so there is no applications like `Disks` where I can do that. I know how to test `read` speed:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb
```

and write speed:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k; rm -f /tmp/output
```

### Problem:

I need more professional way of benchmarking disks like CrystalDisks for Windows, where you can find 4 different technics for testing disks (like **sequential**, **random** ...):

[image]

### Questions:

Is there any package that's gonna allow me benchmarking disks using different technics?

### PS:

This command doesn't point on the disk I wan't to benchmark (`sdb`).

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k; rm -f /tmp/output
```

I have disk `sda`, where my OS is setup, too.

Does this command work or I need to edit it?

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [Benchmark ssd on linux: How to measure the same things as crystaldiskmark does in windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93791/benchmark-ssd-on-linux-how-to-measure-the-same-things-as-crystaldiskmark-does-i) that was asked over on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange so the answers there are relevant here too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`bonnie++`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonnie%2B%2B) will do benchmarks, with many options for how to perform them.

It can be installed with `sudo apt install bonnie++`